# ios - Populating a new view controller with data

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When creating a new view controller to be pushed onto the stack, what is the correct method to use to populate that view controller with data?

I have a data object that I need to send to the view controller, which will then set it's text fields, etc. with the data.

```
ItemDetailViewController_iPad *detailViewController = [[ItemDetailViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
[detailViewController populateWithData:_data];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

in ItemDetailViewController_iPad:

```
-(void) populateWithData:(Item*)_data
{
    self.data = _data;
    self.navigationItem.title = self.data.title;
    self.descriptionText.text = self.data.desc; //the text does not get updated - it's the default text from the nib file
    NSLog(@"Desc: %@", self.data.desc); //this logs valid data

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also declare a property in that VC and then set that property before pushing it.  Then in the viewDidLoad method for the pushed VC, set the view's title and text field.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted should work fine.

There are lots of ways to do this, and it often comes down to what you understand best, feel most comfortable with, and isn't too dull to type in.

Here are some [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012484/tableviewdidselectrowatindexpath-call-to-current-view-parser-delegates/9012811#9012811).